# How to edit/update comment in Jira(Python)

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to edit a comment in jira using jira-python, but I couldn't find anything.

I know `add_comment` will add a comment, but I also want to know how to `edit` a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `comment` is an object, similar to the `issue` so you can make edits in the same way, e.g:

If you know the ID:

```
# '10234' represents the comment id:
comment_to_edit = jira.comment('JIRA-1200', '10234')

comment_to_edit.update(body='Edit the content to something new.')
```

Alternatively if you have assigned the comment to a variable when you create it:

```
comment_to_edit = jira.add_comment('JIRA-1200', 'Change this content later')
comment_to_edit.update(body='New Content.')
```

If you need to find the ID you can get a list of the comments in an issue by:

```
list_of_comments = jira.comments('JIRA-1200')
```

More information can be found in the [Docs](http://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#comments)

Comment: it works. thanks~!! wondering if I can do the following:<br/> issue = jira.issue('JIRA-1200')<br/> issue.update({fields:{comment:{comments:{body:'EDITED'}}}})

Comment: Test it and you'll find out.:)

Comment: Hi GiantsLoveDeathMetal, how do I edit a cusomtfield? try so many ways but none works!! please help.

Comment: @KeithZhen open a new question

Comment: Question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921481/unable-to-edit-custom-fieldjira-python