# Unable to edit custom_field(Jira-Python)

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

Unable to update fields for an issue in Jira-python.

When I look at the raw data in JSON. It is under:

```
{fields:{'customfield_10000':'some text'}
```

but when I tried:

```
issue.update(fields={'customfiled_10000':'edited'})

issue.update({'customfiled_10000':'edited'})

issue.update({fields:{'customfiled_10000':'edited'}})

issue.update(customfiled_10000='edited')
```

All gave me

> response text = {"errorMessages":["Internal server error"],"errors":{}}

Tried added +"0000" in Client.py

`data['started'] = started.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%z")+"+0000"`
still not fixing the issue.
Please Help~!!

**New findings**, when I create a new issue

```
issue= jira.create_issue(fields=root_dict)
```

and i can edit this issue oject using issue.update with no problem

However, when I get the existing issue using

```
issue = jira.issue('JRA-123')
```

editing this issue using issue.update gives me internal error.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/python-jira-add-worklog-giving-internal-error/qaq-p/25548

Comment: tried it, no luck yet.:(

Comment: Have you authed correctly?

Comment: yes, can create an issue, update comments fine. Only can not edit customfields.

Comment: issue = jira.issue("JRA-123")
issue.update(description="ASFASFASD") is it how you get the jira object?

Comment: New findings, I was actually able to use the update method to edit issue on a different database.

I think this is the database server issue. I have contacted IT to look into this. Thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the update part custom**filed** should be customfi**e**ld

```
issue.update({'customfiled_10000':'edited'})
```